# Problem with opening bootstrap 5 modal via typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, bootstrap-5

As you may know bootstrap 5 has been released and for opening modal via JavaScript the official website offer the code below.

```
var myModal = new bootstrap.Modal(document.getElementById('myModal'), options)
myModal.toggle()
```

The problem is I am developing front-end application via Angular 11 strict mode so in this case typescript does not allow me to use `new bootstrap.Modal` because it is not exist.
So please tell me any solutions.

Comment: Have you tried using angular material for modals?

Comment: No I did not use angular material in my project

Comment: How do you import bootstrap?

Comment: I use npm install bootstrap@next for install bootstrap. Then add bootstrap.css and bootstrap js files addresses to angular.json file

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you are trying to use bootstrap with typescript, you will most likely be needing some typings to go along with it. Your setup may vary a bit, but looking at [the documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/getting-started/download/#package-managers) and using the [typings from NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/bootstrap), you can probably get started with

```sh
npm install bootstrap@next @types/bootstrap
```

at this point, if you need to instantiate a plugin, i.e. a modal, the docs specify

> `const bootstrap = require('bootstrap')` or `import bootstrap from 'bootstrap'` will load all of Bootstrap’s plugins onto a bootstrap object. The bootstrap module itself exports all of our plugins. You can manually load Bootstrap’s plugins individually by loading the `/js/dist/*.js` files under the package’s top-level directory.

In your particular case, I believe what you are trying to do is something akin to the following:

```js
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
import { Modal } from 'bootstrap';

const element = document.getElementById('myModal') as HTMLElement;
const myModal = new Modal(element);
myModal.show();
```

Comment: Hi @Felipe I have a react-typescript app, should I use the same npm for install bootstrap or should I install something else?

Comment: @JoaquinPalacios yes, you can use the same npm command. But you will need to use the React `ref` property, and pass that into the `Modal` constructor

Comment: I have to import using "import Modal from 'bootstrap/js/dist/modal'" instead of written above. I'm not sure why but it disrupt bootstrap dropdown menu, causing it unable to show the dropdown.

Answer (score -3):

If you are using bootstrap from CDN, you may do the following:

```
var myModal: any = new (window as any).bootstrap.Modal(
   document.getElementById("my-modal")
);
```

I hope that this will help :)

Comment: That's not a solution, you only bypass type checks by using any.